# Updating Ruby from 2.3 to 4.2 with RVM: "The requested url does not exist(22)"

Tags: ruby, rvm

When running

```
rvm install ruby-4.2.7
```

I get the following error:

```
The requested url does not exist(22): 'https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/4.2/ruby-4.2.7.tar.bz2'
```

It then tries the fallback which also fails. I've run through a couple different SO articles, tried different versions of RVM, and also specified a desired patch level (p95) to no avail.

I think there is something that I don't understand about how that URL is generated. It's my first day at my new job, I'm setting up my environment and this error is killing me!

Thanks!

Comment: There isn't a Ruby version 4.2.7 - the latest version is 2.4.0. There is a 4.2.7 release of Ruby on Rails though.

Comment: Wow... Thanks for confirming that for me. Now I get to make a change to the readme!

Comment: Latest version is actually ruby 2.5.0dev @PhilRoss

Answer (score 0):

You can update Ruby but only to version `2.4.0`.

Try reading "[Installfest](http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/)". That's the quickest Ruby and Rails installation instruction I know and it includes installing RVM.

Comment: The best way to install RVM is to follow [the installation directions](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) on its home page. The authors know more about installing it than anyone. They also show how to install Rails easily. THEN move on to installing other tools.